# Trying to send emails from different email addresses in Meteor.JS

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

I am using Meteor.js and its standard mail package to send emails from different email accounts by the sales team.

I have a default email setting that I trigger at startup

```
Meteor.startup(function () 
{
    console.log('Setting default Email') ; 
    setupEmail( null ) ; 

});
```

I then have the setupEmail function to switch to a new setting or the default depending on passed parameters

```
setupEmail = function( eName, ePass, eServer, ePort )
{
    if( eName )
    {
        smtp = 
        {
            username: eName , 
            password: ePass , 
            server:   eServer, 
            port:  ePort    
        }   
    }       
    else 
    {
        smtp = 
        {
            username: 'aaaaa@bbbbbbbbbbb.com',  // default for mails  
            password: 'xxxxxxxx',   
            server:   'yyy.zzz.com',  
            port: 999 
        }   
    }
```

I then set the Process.env MAIL_URL which is used by Email.Send

```
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;

    console.log(process.env) ; 

    return true ; 
}
```

Then in my Application I can switch to a users email setting calling setupEmail( em, pass, server, port ). Send the email using Email.send() and then switch it back to default setting setupEmail( null )

```
var emailSend = function (from, to, cc, sub, msg, emailObj)
{
  setupEmail(emailObj.email, emailObj.pass, emailObj.server, emailObj.port ) ; 

    ret = Email.send({
        from: from,
        to: to,
        cc: cc, 
        replyTo: to ,
        subject: sub, 
        text: msg
    });

  setupEmail( null, null, null, null ) ;   

  return ret ; 
}
```

It seems to work but the issue I am facing is that as the time between switch to user settings and sending the actual email and then switch back to default settings can vary, another request from a different client can come in and try to send an Email expecting the default setting and when it doesn't find it raises 'RecipientError: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected'

I could ensure all Email.Send calls has a call to set Process.Env to default before calling but think that the timing issue will come back.

What I would like to do is put the

1. change email settings to user
2. email.send
3. change email setting back to default

to be all wrapped in a single non asynch block so that its guaranteed to execute one after the other and no other email send call comes in.

Perhaps I could wrap all this into a single meteor method ... which by default would be blocking { unless I explicitly call this.unblock() } ... could that work ?

Anyone faced a similar challenge ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just put emails into a queue and then have a process that goes through them in mail-server order, that would minimize the context switches while also avoiding locks.

Comment: Hi Michel the issue doesn't seem to be the queue because I tested on localhost and routed all my email sends to a single emailSend Meteor method that sets the MAIL_URL to the settings I pass doesnt switch back ... ie so all email calls will first switch to their settings and then email/ With all normal emails the system works but when I try to switch the settings to a user defined setting it rejects with Error ... 'RecipientError: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected'

Comment: The key issue seems to be switching the  Process.env MAIL_URL. Once its set say during Startup ... it doesnt like further changes and causes this error when I'm changing and sending emails !? strange !

Comment: It may not be possible using Meteor's built-in package. You might try an npm one, ex: https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs - it looks like it can switch between smtp servers on the fly.